# React onBlur event on button does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, sass, safari

I have button with `onClick` and `onBlur`events.

Button contain dropdown ul list inside of body.

And `onBlur`event is needed for "closing dropdown by clicking outside of dropdown"

This is button:

```
<button
    key={title}
    className="filters-item filters-item-btn"
    onClick={(e) => toggleDropdown(e, title)}
    onBlur={(e) => toggleDropdown(e, title)}
  >
      {title}

 // here is dropdown component code (removed)
  </button>
```

This is `toggleDropdown` function

```
 toggleDropdown = (e, title) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title) {
      this.setState({
        titleDropdown: title,
        openedDropdown: !this.state.openedDropdown
      });
    }
  };
```

How to optimize `onBlur` event to work on the button in **Safari and Firefox**?

Comment: Instead of you using Callback function you can bind the function and initialize bind in the constructor. This will help to prevent extra rendering.

Comment: You mean to use refs?

Comment: No ref.
Please have a look into a react doc.
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: This apporach does not work for me cus I need to pass as argument the to toggleDropdown(titile)

Comment: You can add argument as attribute to html.
<button
    key={title}
    data-title= {title}

    className="filters-item filters-item-btn"
    onClick={(e) => toggleDropdown(e, title)}
    onBlur={(e) => toggleDropdown(e, title)}
  >

and in function you can catch using
event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-title");

this will remove the dependency of changing argument in function.